# ClassCastException in executable JAR not inside IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable, classcastexception

I have a problem running my application outside Eclipse. It gives ClassCastException at the place where the application inside IDE does not. In particular, I output to the terminal the name of the instance I'm trying to cast and inside IDE it gives the correct type such as "NestedEngineImpl" whereas outside IDE it gives "EngineImpl" with the exception that EngineImpl cannot be cast to NestedEngineImpl. NestedEngineImple extends EngineImpl.The executable jar has been created using Eclipse' Export Runnable JAR file. The jar opens and runs until the point of exception.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a minimal code snippet that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check versions of your jars. Try this (replace "java/lang/Object.class" with appropriate path to your class):

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getSystemResource("java/lang/Object.class")
```

It will give you URL to your jar, which you can print out to check from where your class is coming).

Comment: +1 - though you should explain that `java/lang/Object.class` needs to be replaced with the path for the class that is causing the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how it might help. I checked the above statement for both classes and have the following: jar:file:/pathToMyExeutable/my.jar!/pathToFirstClass/EngineImpl.class and jar:file:/pathToMyExeutable/my.jar!/pathToSecondClass/NestedEngineImpl.class

Comment: Just to add that pathToFirstClass and pathToSecondClass are the same since both classes are in the same package.

Comment: You should check running inside Eclipse and standalone to see if in both cases the same jar is loaded.

Comment: In Eclipse. the statement gives the same class names that are located in my workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are suffering from what we call `Jar Hell` it is similar to `DLL Hell` where you have a incorrect version of the JAR and you need to replace it with the correct one.  This happens more frequently in large development environments where libraries are constantly being changed.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Is there a Jar Hell fix that can be used in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Thank all for the replies. I simply didn't specify the VM arguments when running the jar that were set in Eclipse.